# Conditional filter with row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample code below of containing an ID, a Date, a Value, along with a row numbered that is partitioned by the ID holder and ordered by their meeting date:

```
SELECT
     c.ID
    ,m.CONTACT_DATE
    ,d.TEST
    ,row_number() over(partition by c.ID 
                       order by m.CONTACT_DATE desc
                      )     [rn]
FROM COMMUNITY C
INNER JOIN MEETING m
    ON c.ID = m.CONTACT_ID
LEFT JOIN DISCUSSION d
    ON m.DISCUSSION_TEST = d.TEST
```

A sample of the results of running such a query would bring:

```
ID      CONTACT_DATE        TEST        rn
01      2017-05-01          NULL        1
01      2017-04-01          1           2
01      2017-03-01          NULL        3
02      2017-08-01          NULL        1
02      2017-09-01          NULL        2
02      2017-10-01          1           3
03      2017-02-01          NULL        1
03      2017-01-01          NULL        2
```

What I'd like to do is group each of the IDs to get the most recent `CONTACT_DATE` (ie. Place in subquery `T`, then `WHERE T.rn = 1 GROUP BY T.ID`)

However, if there's a value under `TEST`, then instead I want to see the most recent `CONTACT_DATE` that has a value, like below:

```
ID      CONTACT_DATE        TEST        rn
01      2017-04-01          1           2
02      2017-10-01          1           3
03      2017-02-01          NULL        1
```

What can I do to filter the most recent `CONTACT_DATE` that has a value under `TEST`, while still getting the most recent `CONTACT_DATE` if all values for that ID is `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your row_number ordering:

```
row_number() over(partition by c.ID 
                       order by CASE WHEN d.TEST IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                      , m.CONTACT_DATE desc
                      )
```

Comment: Shouldn't even need the CASE statement with the supplied example data.  `NULL` coming last in SQL Server so `ORDER BY test, contact_date` would also work...  *(Though yours is indeed more robust to other values being in there...)*

Comment: Nice. So it looks like if I were to go rn = 1, I'd get the most recent values if they have a value under TEST otherwise, just the most recent NULL value. correct?

Comment: That's exactly right. @MatBailie, you're right, it could be simpler, I wanted to show the logic behind this solution though. A straight-forward order by wouldn't be as illustrative, I think.